# align css background to the right

Tags: css, background, background-position

I want to change div background to the right side

i have some css class uses background-position: x,y.

**The css code:**

```
.menu, .bg1, .bg2 {
    background-image:url(bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.bg1 {
    background-position: 0px 5px;
}
.bg2 {
    background-position: 0px 15px;
}
```

all I want to show padding and background on right side!

```
padding-right: 50px;
```

how i can move background position to the right side without need to change x,y position, just align it to right side?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SkL43/

Comment: `I want to change div background to the right side` you know this is not much understandable?

Comment: @RokoC.Bulijan I just edited it as you posted that...

Comment: I wants to shift the background to the right without changing the  bg1 and bg2 background positions, now it display background on left side, but I want to show it on right sides. when I add background-position to right to main class, bg1 and bg2 not display selected position and display outside. hope you understand!

Comment: Don't understand add a fiddle or something... how do you expect to shift the background without change the background-position?

Comment: how can fix it with changing background-position? is it effect to bg1 and bg2 background positions?

Comment: Yes if you have defined background-positions you need to override those porperties. i don't know what you really want post an image or fiddle

Comment: like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/SkL43/11/ tell me and i post it as an answer

Comment: yes like that, it work

Comment: @Danko I was thinking about the same solution. But he said not to change the position :-/

Comment: @irplayboy post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `background-position` you can do declarations like:

```
background-position: center right;
```

Here the first values is Horizontal and Second Vertical.

**Edit**

After see you Fiddle i came to this solution: **http://jsfiddle.net/SkL43/11/**

You need to change the first value of the `background-position` to take it just to the right:

```
.bg1 {
  background-position: 100% 0px;
}
```

Comment: He's already done that, he's saying he wants to shift the background to the right *without* changing the original background position property... I think... the question is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: He says don't change x,y position i guess he refers to fixed values

Answer (score 0):

add `position:relative` and `right:0px;` to what ever div your image is in

Comment: can yoyu create a fiddle of your code please because I think your question was a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to keep your image offset from the right hand side. If so, you can do this by using the [four-value syntax](http://briantree.se/quick-tip-06-use-four-value-syntax-properly-position-background-images/) for background positioning or you could use the [css calc() function](http://briantree.se/quick-tip-02-use-css-calc-properly-position-background-images/).